# How to handle differnet purched price and quantity in same product

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, logic

I'm developing a automobile parts inventory system using PHP and Mysql. This system have purchase module to add/update/increase quantity of parts & sale module to decrease/out the quantity of parts. my query have 2 section

A. Storing data

1. Suppose we have PARTS A1 in our stock with quantity 30 and the price of PARTS A1 was $20 when we purchase it.
2. Now we want to stock this parts more for example we want to buy 50 more items of PARTS A1 but now new price of PARTS A1 is $24.

What is best way/logic to make these items separate to know how much parts are purchased with price $20 and new price $24 on sale page.

```
1. Store same parts more then once in database
2. Normalize Database: parts HasMany partTransctions with purchased price and quantity
```

B. Retrieving Data

1. what will be the decrease method when sale (suppose 60 unit in above example) A1 parts
2. also I want to calculate the the profit of the sale

How to handle all of those situation. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2. Normalize Database: parts HasMany partTransctions with purchased price and quantity

or

You can handle this issue using Batch by purchase. You need to create a table called purchaseBatches. This table will store every purchase history.
Transaction table `partTransctions` will be store batchID. That's it.
I think, you know the next steps.

Also in sale you need to find the method of LIFO or FIFO & many of sales rate manage by average value by calculate with other costs.

Comment: Why need purchaseBatches table, I can store purchased price and quantity both in this partTransctions table.
FIFO and AverageValue idea will help me @abdur-rob

Comment: purchaseBatches table can reduce your redundancy data.
And Yes, you can store those data in partTransctions table too.

Hmm, you can use FIFO and averageValue methon. I always use this methods. ;)